# Proof Explanation - Post update.

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I could not find a similar question - so please tell me if this is a duplicate.

I find myself often in the situation where I need explanation for a proof I read from a text, whether regarding definition, or a simple step. In most cases, the proof is not short, and I would have to break down the question and post in separately on MSE. I fear if I do so, I would be spamming MSE with 3 or 4 questions at once.

I thought of three possible choices:

i) Post separate questions (around 3)

ii) updating the same post with a new problem (rewriting the old)

iii) Post all questions in one long post; which is tedious for the reader.

I wonder which of the above choices - or other alternatives - is better for the MSE community?

PS. Alternatively, if there is a "hide" feature (requested elsewhere in this site) I could make a single post that contains all the questions, and content (which is useful, as sometimes I also have to copy definitions, and a hide bar would really help out).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the three questions can be answered independently, then I would encourage you to make three different posts. Also you called this "spamming" I don't see any reason why it's a bad thing. I would link to the previous posts in each subsequent post, which allows readers to see the broader context and links them internally on the site.